# os.stat fails when executed from python script

Tags: python-3.x, linux

When I do `os.stat` in the Python REPL, I get a successful result

```py
>>> print (rec[1].value)
/project/img-5.pdf
>>> os.stat(rec[1].value)
os.stat_result(st_mode=33279, st_ino=7735271, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=202239, st_atime=1618133113, st_mtime=1618153952, st_ctime=1618141989)
```

but the same `os.stat` command run in python script fails

```py
print(rec[1].value)
os.stat(rec[1].value)
```

with the following error:

```py
os.stat(rec[1].value)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FileName'
```

Comment: Looks like you have extra characters in the filename. What does print(rec[1].value) show in the script?

Comment: @RamanSailopal, I get exactly as shown above i.e /project/img-5.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final `FileNotFoundError` says that *FileName* is not found.
That means `rec[1].value` is set to `FileName` and not to `/project/img-5.pdf` as you want.

Comment: Thanks, after rechecking my program, noticed that the variable had incorrect value and so os.stat failed.